# alternative to ifelse in data.table

Tags: r, if-statement, data.table

I have very big two data.table: A and B.
The code below works fine, but it is very slow.

```
temp2=ifelse(is.na(A) & is.na(B),FALSE,
               ifelse(!is.na(A) & is.na(V),TRUE,
                      ifelse(is.na(A) & !is.na(B),FALSE,
                             ifelse(A!=B,TRUE,FALSE))))
```

is there any better alternative so the code will run faster?

Comment: What is V?  Is that meant to be B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since all you need is "true" or "false" returned, it does not seem like you need to use ifelse at all.

If I am reading this correctly (and assuming you meant B not V), then whenever `A` is `NA`, you want `false` returned, regardless of the value of B.  Thus, in order for `true` to be returned, `A` must not be `NA`.  Next, in order for `true` to be returned, A cannot equal B.  But, if `B` is `NA`, `NA` will be returned from testing `A != B`.  And, if `B` is `NA`, but `A` is not, you want `TRUE`, so:

```
temp2 = (!is.na(A))&((A!=B)|is.na(B))
```

Should do the trick.  If you did mean V, then you have three data.tables?

Concerning timing,

```
require(data.table)

A<- data.table(v1=sample(c(1,2,NA),1e6,replace=TRUE),v2=sample(c(1,2,NA),1e6,replace=TRUE))
B<- data.table(v1=sample(c(1,2,NA),1e6,replace=TRUE),v2=sample(c(1,2,NA),1e6,replace=TRUE))

system.time({temp1 = (!is.na(A))&((A!=B)|(is.na(B)))})
##   user  system elapsed 
##   0.41    0.00    0.41

system.time({temp2 =ifelse(is.na(A) & is.na(B),FALSE,
                                       ifelse(!is.na(A) & is.na(B),TRUE,
                                              ifelse(is.na(A) & !is.na(B),FALSE,
                                                     ifelse(A!=B,TRUE,FALSE))))})
##   user  system elapsed 
##   2.56    0.11    2.68 

all.equal(temp1,temp2)
## true
```

So, its about 6 times faster.